# Creating Spring Boot Aplication Context for integration tests with JAX-RS and Spring failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jax-rs, integration-testing, verifyerror

We have introduced SpringBoot in our application. Now we use JAX-RS and Spring together. I `@Autowire` a Spring `@Service` in my rest resource which is a `@Component`. In my service there is a method with `@Transactional`. All this works fine in the production code.
I wanted to create a integration test for that and there my application context couldn't be loaded. I use a h2 in-memory database.
Here my other configurations:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myrepopackee")
@PropertySource("classpath:integrationtest.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class IntegrationtestConfig
```

and in the integration test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {IntegrationtestConfig.class, JerseyConfig.class, ResourceIntegrationtestConfiguration.class})
@Sql({"classpath:sql/import.sql"})
public class ReportResourceITest {
```

I got following output:

```
3822  ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reportResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageSenderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSenderService' defined in file [pat-to-project/target/classes/com/organization/services/MessageSenderService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:352)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:204)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:352)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1624)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:351)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageSenderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSenderService' defined in file [pat-to-project/target/classes/com/organization/services/MessageSenderService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSenderService' defined in file [pat-to-project/target/classes/com/organization/services/MessageSenderService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:471)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 9
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/organization/services/MessageSenderService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c941318c.<init>()V @9: athrow
  Reason:
    Current frame's flags are not assignable to stack map frame's.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { 'java/lang/RuntimeException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @9
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a59 b701 2ab8 0038 b1bf bb00 4e5a 5fb7
    0000010: 0051 bf                                
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 9
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 9
    bci [0, 9] => handler: 10
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@9,{},{Object[#76]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@10,Object[#76])
```

...

I tried it with openjdk 8, 11 and 14. **When i remove the @Transactional annotations in my service the context is loaded!**
I hope anyone can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dependency issue. The problem was that the dependency spring-boot-startet-jersey includes an older version of spring-aop so I excluded it:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```